# method sum in classs sample cannot be applied to given typpe

Tags: java

hello guys below is my java code and iam getting an error please help to slove this, and can i get a brief explaination why this error is occuring. thanks in advance.

```
  the below is my code:
```

public class sample {

```
            static double sum( double x ,double y) {

             return x + y;



     }

    static double avg( double x , double y) {

     double sum = sum(x + y);

     return sum/2;



   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   double d = sum(3.0, 2.0);

   System.out.println(d);

   double d2=avg(1.0 , 2,0);

   System.out.println(d2);



  }
```

}

***************and am getting the following error for this code**********************

```
    sample.java:7: error: method sum in class sample cannot be applied to given types;

            double sum = sum(x + y);

            required: double,double

             found:    double

            reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: You are using sum(x + y), but you need to use it as sum(x, y)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is from your avg method

```java
static double avg( double x , double y) {

     double sum = sum(x + y);

     return sum/2;



  }
```

You have use another signature here

```java
double sum = sum(x + y);
```

instead, replace it with

```java
double sum = sum(x , y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `avg()` like this:

```
double d2 = avg(1.0, 2.0);
```